# Earth, Moon, gravitatioal pull

Tags: newtonian-gravity, earth, moon, tidal-effect

Does the gravitational pull that causes tides, also affect the Earth's land mass. Does it affect the atoms, molecules, is there a slight bulge to the actual Earth / Land itself?

Comment: I think you could improve some points of your question:
1 Elaborate what do you mean with "affect the earth's land mass".


2 "Does it affect the atoms/molecule?" What do you mean with that? If it affects the structure of the atom? The gravitational pull that causes tides, that is the resulting of the gravitaional field of the sun and the moon, is too weak to change the structure of an atom.


3 "Is there a bulge to the actual Earth itself?"  Elaborate it.

4 Your first expression start with "Does", but there is no "?" in the end, there is a ".", Should it be interpret as what?

Comment: for example see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_tide.  this is of interest https://news.stanford.edu/pr/99/atomgravity990825.html

Comment: Tides do exist in landmass, pack and atmosphere.